# How did an uninitialised pointer create a SegFault in cin?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, cin

I declared a pointer but did not initialise it. But because of this, I get a segfault in a cin statement which has got nothing to do with the pointer. Here is the code:

```
char tempBuff[20];
char ** stat;
cout<<"All fine till here...";
cin>>tempBuff;
cout<<"Gotcha!";
```

And here is the output, where 12 is the number entered:

```
All fine till here...12
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It works fine if the pointer `stat` is initialised to `NULL`. If I get to know why this happened, it would help me not commit the same mistake again.

Thanks!

**Update:** Since no one was able to reproduce the error with the code snippet I gave, [here](http://pastebin.com/VBRJcCqS) is the entire code. I compiled the code on GCC version 4.8.4 to get the error.

Comment: It is working [here](https://ideone.com/ZPqrBx).  Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: I suspect that you have some code surrounding that code.

Comment: @NathanOliver [Here](http://pastebin.com/VBRJcCqS) is my entire code.

Comment: @daltonfury42 Your full code is still [working](https://ideone.com/ZPqrBx).  Also `newStud.status == tempBuff[0];` and `newStud.status == 'P';` is not assigning but comparing.

Comment: @NathanOliver It definitely does not work on gcc version 4.8.4. WHich compiler did you use?

Comment: @daltonfury42 ideone uses 5.1 I think.

Answer (score 1):

You are being misled by `stdout`'s buffering. If you add an explicit flush :

```
cout << "Gotcha!" << std::flush;
```

You will get the following output :

```
./chose 
All fine till here...12
Gotcha!Segmentation Fault
```

Running it with `valgrind` produces the following errors :

```
==5817== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5817==    at 0x569E68B: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:489)
==5817==    by 0x400BAF: addStudent() (chose.cpp:21)
==5817==    by 0x400C53: main (chose.cpp:30)
==5817== 
==5817== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5817==    at 0x569E68D: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:490)
==5817==    by 0x400BAF: addStudent() (chose.cpp:21)
==5817==    by 0x400C53: main (chose.cpp:30)
==5817== 
==5817== 
==5817== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5817==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x400A29
==5817==    at 0x569E68D: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:490)
==5817==    by 0x400BAF: addStudent() (chose.cpp:21)
==5817==    by 0x400C53: main (chose.cpp:30)
```

Which point at the following instruction :

```
newStud.mark = strtol(tempBuff, stat, 10);
```

Indeed, you provided your uninitialised pointer to [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), which then tested it against `NULL` (hence "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)").

Then, seeing that it was not (it contains arbitrary, but non-zero garbage in your case), went ahead and stored its end pointer at this location, triggering a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the pointer elsewhere in the code?  From my experience segfaults do not necessarily occur where you expect them to be.  They do not even always occur when there really is an error.  For instance if that uninitialized pointer happens to point somewhere in your allowed address space you wont get a segfault.  This happens a lot when you run off the end of arrays.

What is maybe happening here is that when you declare stat you are changing what the stack looks like which is also where tempBuff resides in memory.  This may cause a segfault in one case and no error in another, hard to say since you don't really know what the compiler is doing with your code.  If you are on a linux platform I would try running it though a program called valgrind which checks your memory.

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is *buffered* - output is written when the buffer is full; when `cin` is read; or when `cout` is explicitly flushed, either using `flush()` or by writing `std::endl`.

In your case, this causes the output to be deceiving, as your program crashes after `cout<<"Gotcha!";` but before the buffer has been flushed.

The cause of the crash is that you never initialise `stat`, and dereferencing it is, as both your code and `strol` do, is undefined.

*However*, your code is undefined even if you initialise it to `NULL`, since dereferencing a null pointer is also undefined (I have no idea why your code doesn't crash in that case, but such is the nature of undefined behaviour. The compiler may have removed the test since it knows that it's an invalid dereference and thus can't happen in a valid program.).

If you're interested in the "end pointer" from `strtol`, you should pass it a pointer to a variable:

```
    char * stat = NULL;
    cout<<"All fine till here...";
    cin>>tempBuff;
    cout<<"Gotcha!";
    student newStud;
    newStud.mark = strtol(tempBuff, &stat, 10);
    if(stat)
            newStud.status == tempBuff[0];
    else
            newStud.status == 'P';
```

I'm not sure what your intent is with the final test, as `strtol` always returns a valid pointer in the "end" parameter.
(It's one-past-the-end of the converted value if conversion succeeded, the value of the first parameter otherwise.)

The moral of this is: when trace-debugging, always write an `endl` (or use `cerr` instead of `cout`).

Comment: `std::cout` is also flushed when the code calls an extractor on `std::cin`. That makes input prompts show up before the program waits for input.